# Magento 2 Success default message in same phtml file

Tags: php, magento, controller, block

i want to print the success message (which Magento2 default message format) after click on the submit button. so if the all feild are validated then there should be success message on same phtml file that "Your Data is validate!", i want to know how to do this from basic because i don't have idea about it ::

code for my block file ::

```
` <?php
namespace Test\Validation\Block;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
    protected $helper;
    protected $_messageManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        array $data = []) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }
    public function successmessage($message){
        $this->_messageManager->addSuccess(__($message));
    }

}`
```

~~Thank you, in advance 1!

Answer (score 0):

It should be done in a controller but not in the block.
Look the example in the native magento contact module here \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The message manager is directly used in execute method without defining variable in __construct() in '\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post' file, so it will, to directly use message manager in execute()?